# MEAN stack Service Workers

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs, service-worker

I am using the MEAN stack using the Google's read-through-caching example.
Everytime I load or refresh, the error is

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null(…)
in ([the following code, line 112](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/read-through-caching/index.html#L112) ).

I changed the class from #status to #ng-scope to meet the main class to cache

> document.querySelector('#ng-scope').textContent = error;

[HTML file modification relative to the class it needs to cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YAjr.png)

It still works but it's showing the error in red. I tried other solutions evaluating if the value is null but no luck or I am probably doing it wrong.